# Dynamic ID in Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, ejs

I am making something where I have dynamic ID for element i.e something like this in my index.ejs

```
<% for ( var i= 0; i<100; i++ ) { %>
     <th> <span class="Pr" id=price"<%=i%>">$<%= result[i]["price"] %></span></th>
<%} %>
```

This should generate ID which increments with i for example price1, price2 and so on..

Now I am using `Socket.io` to obtain new data. After obtaining the new data, I want to change the `innerHTML`

Traditionally, I know I can do something like

```
 document.getElementsByID("id").innerHTML = newData;
```

But I knew the ID there well in advance, Here the ID obtained is when the data obtained from socket.io matches my iTH element

```
document.getElementById('price' + i).innerHTML
```

I was hoping that this would make `my ID as price0, price1, price2` (when i=0,1,2) but this doesn't seem to be working.

Please do let me know how I can fix this?

Comment: "Doesn't seem to be working". Where are you getting `i` from in your example?  We'll need more clarification and a full snip of what you've attempted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There appears to be quotes in your id attribute, which would produce ids like

```
id=price"0"
id=price"1"
id=price"2"
```

As you can see that is incorrect formatting. Change to:

```
id="price<%=i%>"
```

Which will produce the correctly formatted attributes:

```
id="price0"
id="price1"
id="price2"
```

Answer (score 0):

I try dynamic ID using your code it is working fine.

You can see this

```js
for (let i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
    document.getElementById('price' + i).innerHTML ="test";
}
```

```html
<span class="Pr" id="price0">price0</span>
<span class="Pr" id="price1">price1</span>
<span class="Pr" id="price2">price2</span>
<span class="Pr" id="price3">price3</span>
```